# Distinguishing a record instance from a map

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to call `clojure.walk/stringify-keys` on a map that might include record instances.  Since stringify-keys is recursive, it attempts to convert the keys on my record, (since `(map? record-var)` is true) which causes an error.  Is there any way to tell if a var is a record rather than just a Clojure map?  I
d like to provide my own implementation of `stringify-keys` that is record-aware.

The current implementation of `stringify-keys` causes the following:

```lisp
(use '[clojure.walk :only [stringify-keys]])

(defrecord Rec [x])    

(let [record (Rec. "foo")
      params {:x "x" :rec record}]
    (stringify-keys params))
```

This causes the following exception: UnsupportedOperationException Can't create empty: user.Rec  user.Rec (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Records seem to implement the IRecord marker interface:

```
user=> (defrecord Rec [x])    
user.Rec

user=> (require '[clojure.reflect :as r])
nil
user=> (:bases (r/reflect Rec))
#{java.io.Serializable clojure.lang.IKeywordLookup clojure.lang.IPersistentMap clojure.lang.IRecord java.lang.Object clojure.lang.IObj clojure.lang.ILookup java.util.Map}

user=> (instance? clojure.lang.IRecord (Rec. "hi"))
true
```

***Update***
1.6 now has the `record?` functions

Answer (score 1):

you can check the type of each member and see if it is really a map or something else (where something else is presumed to be a record)

```
user> (type {:a 1 :b 2})
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```